# OpenCV android - How to recognize specific objects

Tags: android, opencv, machine-learning, opencv3.0

I have been making application which recognize car light symbols on Android in Java using OpenCV. I take the images from phone's camera. I use OpenCV 3.2.0 version. What I have done so far:

1. Filter out the colors in an image
2. Reduce the noise
3. Detect an object by size
4. Sort out the object by color(the object will be compared with the same object's color)

Detected object:

[image: Detected object]

Colors filtered out:

[image: Colors filtered out]

What would be good option to recognize those (binary images) objects? I took a look at HOG, HAAR and k-NN algorithms. But I struggle to get some useful information about it(where to download files with algorithms or train the algorithms ).Or do I miss something?  I do on windows 10 everything. Let know your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

HAAR would be a good way to detect a specific sign. Assuming you know how to train your cascade models you can find a good example in Java [here](http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/06-face-detection-and-tracking.html) to use your models to recognize signs.

But if you don't know how to train your HAAR models you can refer to [OpenCV reference](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html). It's a bit complicated to train your HAAR models using the command line tools of OpenCV but [here](http://amin-ahmadi.com/cascade-trainer-gui/) there's a good GUI to train your models.

Then you can train a model for each sign and recognize signs in images using classifiers for each sign but it will be a bit time consuming

**Update:**

To learn your cascade model the command line and the official way (OpenCV 3.x), you can try [this](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html).

Comment: I thank you for your answer. I have seen in the version opencv 3.x, you can train your models in a project with opencv. There are classes which allow to do it. You don't have to have any other program to train it. Or did I mess up something? I am not sure.

Comment: Actually training rich models such as cascade models is a development time process; so the way OpenCV itself provides is to use its command line tools as is described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html). But training simpler models such as training a SVM can be done using OpenCV classes.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. Wouldn't it be much simpler to match shapes? Or Are training algorithms much realible? Because I think those algorithms are for lot of images to recognize. for now I have been making recognition by matching shapes.

Comment: What do you mean by matching shapes? If you mean to simply find polygons and circles in the image it is OK to find the sign location; but what about the sign contents (e.g. a circular sign may be either a "pedestrian prohibited" sign or a "horn prohibited" sign)?

Comment: I mean, in the opencv I can find contours of the object which I take from camera. I do the same with object in high quality. After that I compare contours and then I get value how similar they are.

Comment: It's all OK but choosing or inventing a good similarity measure between contours is a big deal itself. There are some methods for that to be done. I think a more general learning approach would be better because it will be intuitively more robust assuming you can gather as much data as you need.